# Incorrect median and mode

Tags: c, statistics, median

Details of the problem are mentioned below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int N, i, j, sum, mode, count, f[100], maxf;
    float mean, med;

    printf("Enter the number of students\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Number of students:%d\n", N);

    int m[N];  // Array to store the marks //

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter the marks of student %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &m[i]);
    }

    printf("Scores\n");

    for (j = 0; j < N; j += 5) {
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", m[j], m[j + 1], m[j + 2], m[j + 3], m[j + 4]);
    }

    // Sorting the array //

    for (i = 0; i < (N - 1); i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (m[j] < m[i]) {
                int temp = m[j];
                m[j] = m[i];
                m[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    if (N % 2 == 0) {
        med = (((m[((N / 2) - 1)] + m[(N / 2)])) / 2);
    } else
    if (N % 2 != 0) {
        med = m[((N + 1) / 2)];
    }

    sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += m[i];
    }

    mean = (((float)(sum)) / (N));

    printf("Mean:%f\n", mean);
    printf("Median:%d", med);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (m[j] != -1) {
                if (m[j] == m[i]) {
                    count += 1;
                    m[j] = -1;
                }

                count = f[i];                      // Array to store frequency //
            }
        }
    }

    maxf = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       if (maxf < f[i]) {
           maxf = f[i];
       }   
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (maxf == f[i]) {
            printf("Mode: %d\n", m[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting median to come some value but it is coming `0` every time and I am always getting an incorrect mode.

Comment: This for loop     for (j = 0; j < N; j += 5) {
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", m[j], m[j + 1], m[j + 2], m[j + 3], m[j + 4]);
    } is unsafe if N is not divisible by 5.

Comment: Should it be med = m[N / 2]; instead of med = m[((N + 1) / 2)];?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not test the return values of `scanf()`: you will have undefined behavior if any of the input is missing or causes a conversion error.
- when printing the values, you assume `N` to be a multiple of `5`: you will have undefined behavior accessing elements beyond the end of the array if it is not the case.
- you compute the *median* value in case of an even number of elements as the average of the values of the central elements of the array: you should use floating point arithmetics for this computation by casting at least one of the operands as a `float` or `double`.  For example:

  ```
    med = ((float)m[N / 2 - 1] + m[N / 2]) / 2;
  ```
- in case of an odd number of elements, you should take the value of the central element, which is **not** at offset `(N + 1) / 2` but simply at offset `N / 2`.  You should check such formulas with trivial cases, eg N=1 -> med=m[(1+1)/2] out of range!

  ```
    med = m[N / 2];
  ```

  Note that you can use the formula `med = ((float)m[(N - 1) / 2] + m[N / 2]) / 2;` in all cases, assuming `N > 0`.
- `printf("Median:%d", med)` has undefined behavior because you pass a `float` value (which is automatically converted to a `double`) where `printf` expects an `int` for the conversion `%d`.  You should use `%f` instead:

  ```
    printf("Median: %f\n", med);
  ```
- to compute the mode, you use an array `f[100]` which will be too small if `N > 100`.
- you never store `count` to `f[i]`, instead you read `count` from `f[i]` which is uninitialized.
- furthermore, you do not reset `count` to `0` or `1` for each different value in `m`.
- the *mode* of the array is the number that appears more times in the array than any other number.  You can determine this without an extra array by computing the maximum number of duplicates in a linear scan and print the values with this number of duplicates in a subsequent scan.

Comment: Thanks a million mate for such a comprehensive solution